# Starbucks'/Starbucks Song

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

Let's say I frequent Starbucks, and there a particular song gets played so often that I start to associate Starbucks with that song. Would saying

> I like Starbucks'/Starbucks song.

or

> Do you know the actual name of Starbucks' song?

be idiomatic and acceptable in that case, even though that song was not composed by them? If so, should I say Starbucks' song or Starbucks song?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the name of the shop as an attributive noun.  Using "Starbucks" is confusing, so let's imagine we have heard the song at "Costa" coffee shop.

> I really like that "Costa song". You know, the one they always play. Do you know the actual name of the "Costa song"?.

The quote marks in the writing show the meaning to "The thing that I call..."

I wouldn't use "Costa's song", unless it was particularly owned by them.

Using "Starbucks" is difficult, because when brand names are possessives, they often omit the apostrophe.  Consider "Waterstones" or "Barclays Bank" Others include it "McDonald's" or "Wendy's".  We don't really want to form a possessive of a word that is already a possessive.

The solution is to sidestep the problem:

> I really like that song that they play in Starbucks. Do you know the actual name of the song they always play in Starbucks?

Simple. No need to form possessives at all.

Answer (score 3):

"Starbucks" is the singular name of the company, so you don't need the possessive "s" at the end.  If you mean to make it possessive, then add an "'s"

> Starbucks's song

or, better yet, make it a compound noun:

> Starbucks song

Otherwise, this kind of comment is perfectly grammatical, but I can't say it would make much sense.  I would expect that you are talking about the official [*jingle*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/jingle) of the Starbucks company, which, as far as I know, does not exist (unlike companies such as MacDonald's, who has had [various jingles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsuGr4W_QJQ) over the years).

So each time you'd probably have to explain what you mean by "Starbucks song", e.g.:

> I mean the song that I hear all the time when I go to Starbucks.

Comment: The form Starbucks' given here is  absolutely incorrect "Starbucks" is a singular noun (albeit a proper one) Its possesivbe should be "Starbucks's " The form "s'" should **only** be used when the s is a result of the word beign in a plural form. Many people, even native speakers get this wrong, and usage may eventually change this rule, but it hasn't happened yet. See *Strunk  and White* Rule 1: "Form the possessive singular of nouns by adding 's".  The first example given there is "Charles's, not Charles'"

Comment: @DavidSiegel  huh, looks like I've been doing it wrong all this time.  Just goes to show.  Edited.

Comment: downvote converted to upvote. Thanks

Comment: @DavidSiegel It is not absolutely incorrect; it's a matter of style, and various well-regarded style guides have conflicting advice. See this round up: https://www.dailywritingtips.com/possessive-of-proper-names-ending-in-s/

Comment: What if it's the song of several Starbuckseses?

Comment: @Katy agreed, but if Strunk and White say that's how you do it, I'm willing to give them the benefit of the doubt. I still think that the other way is acceptable, but style guides will vary so we just do the best we can.

Comment: One thing that makes this more complex is that "Starbucks" is a brand name which suggests "Of Starbuck" (the Moby Dick character) Brand names that are possessives often (not always) omit the apostrophe. What if the song had been playing at "McDonald's" ?    The "compound noun" suggestion seems the best solution.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Adding *'s* is only the common current style. And doing it differently is *not* "absolutely incorrect." It used to be that you would simply add an apostrophe without another *s*. And although that's no longer common, it *is* still done by some people today.